# Manytoone object not loading after repository.save - Eager fetch not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am unable to find a way to load the N+1 objects. I am sending their Ids but the entire object is expected to load because of eager fetch but it doesn't work. I tried even @Fetch annotation. Not sure what's missing

```
 package com.example.manytonetest;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table
    public class Department {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private int id;

      @Column
      private String name;

      public int getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

    }

package com.example.manytonetest;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOne;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOneOption;

@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "dep_id")
  private Department department;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
  }

  public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
  }

}


  @PostMapping
  public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee e) {
    e = employeeRepository.save(e);
    return e;
  }
```

Input:

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null
    }
}
```

There exists a department with id 1 with name IT in DB.

Output from Rest API:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC",
    "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null
    }
}
```

Why is department object not loading even though it's eager fetch? What should I do to make it load?

Comment: How can you sure it is  not loaded ? Check log what query executed .

Comment: I am not getting in response

Comment: Department Name is not fetch that's why ?

Comment: Yes, department name should come back in response

Comment: Check db is there already not null value for department of id 1 ?

Comment: Nope. it has a name

Comment: After post department name should be updated

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/database-table-relationships/ and https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/ or this https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-jpa-manytoone-relationship-to-a-sql-query-using-the-hibernate-joinformula-annotation/